# How can I debug my wireless problem?

Tags: wireless, debugging, debug

How can I get started with debugging my wireless problem?

- How can I tell whether or not Linux has recognized my wireless hardware at all?
- What are the main programs/daemons associated with wireless connectivity?
- Where are the log files for those programs?
- Do those programs have debug modes that I can access?
- How can I tell whether a bug is in a userspace program or in a driver?

Edit: This was originally a more complex question with other inquiries about wireless driver hacking and debugging.  I have removed those bullet points and plan to create another question to cover them, possibly on Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: You really need to split these up into multiple questions, there's just too much to cover here in one question.

Comment: @JorgeCastro, good idea.  What do you suggest?  User-land driver diagnostics and Intel driver hacking?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into at least covers some, the rest you can probably ask seperate

Comment: For a script to get the information below and more besides, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Answer (score 22):

Behold the power of the terminal!

*List PCI devices / wifi network relevant portion only*

```
$ lspci -v | grep -iA 7 network
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

*Look for correctly loading modules*

```
$ lsmod | grep <your module>
```

In this case, the module is `iwlwifi`.

*Show kernel messages related to your module*

```
$ dmesg | grep <your module>
```

*List hardware config for your network*

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
```

*Show and/or configure network interface(s)*

```
$ ifconfig
```

*Show and/or configure wireless interface(s)*

```
$ iwconfig
```

*Scan your network*

```
$ iwlist scan
```

*Network-manager configuration (graphical and CLI)*

```
$ nmtui
$ nmcli
```

*Show switches for your wifi device*

```
$ rfkill list all
```

If you want more detailed info/debug options you can run `man <command>` for each of them.

If you have wireless problems, post the output of these commands and we'll help you. Not all of them are necessary, but the more info the better.

For log files, check out the `/var/log/` directory.  The `dmesg`, `boot` and `xorg.0.log` files are generally the most useful ones, at least in my experience. For wifi stuff `dmesg` will do.

Comment: +1 for the nice overview. Maybe a *method* might be nice here too. Something like *step 1, step 2, ...*.

Comment: `nm-tool` is no longer available, now [we have `nmcli` and **`nmtui`**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617067/why-nm-tool-is-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-15-04).