# How do I make wireless connection?

Tags: wireless, networking

I've tried many distros and invariably am unable to make a wireless connection.
In some cases, I don't even receive the wireless option for setup.
I'm running an Inspiron 1720, NIC1395, 32 bit, 6GB RAM.
i've installed/uninstalled ndiswrapper, BCM4401-B0, BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY.
I tried using Linksys adapter AE2500 but no linux software; then tried WUSB54GSC and tried to install software using Wine.
I've run out of ideas...can U help?
Thanx in advance.
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Below is a link to Ubuntu Desktop Help Guide for version 12.04.  In it you will find instructions for making a wireless connection and even a troubleshooter to diagnose the problem.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless.html

In general, the more information you give, the better the community can answer your question.  For instance, what version of Ubuntu are you using?  What are the Make and Model of your wireless network interface card?  Here is a link to a thread's answer that gives the Terminal commands for that information:

[How can I debug my wireless problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258616/how-can-i-debug-my-wireless-problem)

Please try these links and reply to your post with more information and/or specific errors or questions.

Here's just some useful info for new Linux users:

http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Familiar-With-Ubuntu-Commands