# NetworkManager does not start / fails to start and they say it's not a bug (#1489154)

Tags: wireless, 15.10, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

After rebooting,  NetworkManager all of the sudden has stopped working. Its icon appeared in the tray, then disappeared, then appeared again and so on 3-4 times.

All my config files are correct, I simply haven't changed anything.

I found this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1489154

However, it seems overcomplicated.

I have internet connection now, though, via wpa_supplicant.

So what do I do to fix it?

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy network-manager`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, N: Unable to locate package network-manage

Comment: It's `network-manager`, not `network-manage`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, network-manager:
  Installed: 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.2
  Candidate: 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I don't think I need to.

Answer (score 1):

Is that your bug ? If so read the bug report

> Please refer to comments #8 and #11. This is not a bug and has been
>   closed.

The really mean comment #7 which give a detailed description of why this is "not a bug" and what to do to resolve the problem.

> This isn't a bug -- we're blocking packages in wily-proposed
>   specifically because they can be slightly broken, and the tests that
>   failed and currently block promotion of the package are meant to do
>   just that -- block things that may be a little buggy. From there,
>   partial upgrades make things even worse, since you may be missing
>   important part of underlying libraries.

and later ...

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23 \
    libnm0=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23 libnm-glib4=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23 \
    libnm-util2=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23 \
    gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23
```

so, run

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23 \
    libnm0=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23 libnm-glib4=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23 \
    libnm-util2=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23 \
    gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0=0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23
```

If that does not fix your problem or that is not your bug you are barking up the wrong tree and we need more information.

Comment: And what will happen when I call apt update, upgrade next time?

Comment: I don't know, do you have the proposed repository enabled ? If so, disable it. You are asking me to guess without telling me about your system or even if this is your bug.

Comment: Whose bug can it be?

Comment: That bug was filed by https://launchpad.net/~laza74 . Are you having the same bug or are you just trying random solutions ? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/258616/how-can-i-debug-my-wireless-problem and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Comment: I have the same bug.

Comment: so did you run the commands given to you in the bug report ? did that fix the problem ? did you disable the proposed repositories ?

Comment: Reading state information... Done
E: Version '0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23' for 'network-manager' was not found
E: Version '0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23' for 'libnm0' was not found
E: Version '0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23' for 'libnm-glib4' was not found
E: Version '0.9.10.0-4ubuntu23' for 'libnm-util2' was not found
E: Unable to locate package gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0'
alex@blackanbookub15:~$ sudo apt-cache policy network-manage

Comment: So that is not really the same bug or same solution. Go through the links I gave you and update your question with the required information and you may need to file a new bug report.