# Wifi not working in Ubuntu in Acer aspire e5

Tags: wireless

I am trying to establish a wireless connection but it's not connecting. I searched for the wireless driver but was not found. Please instruct me how to install the wireless driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my wireless problem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/258616/how-can-i-debug-my-wireless-problem)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen But they haven't mentioned anything about installing the wireless driver.

Comment: @VishnuNK - the wireless drivers are part of the kernel and we know not what card so first step is to identify hardware. Unless you know what driver to install , in which case, go ahead and answer.

Comment: please see the link I provided and update your question with relevant information. Simply stating it is not working does not provide sufficient information to provide support.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Notebook Acer E5-574G-77Z7
I was unable to install ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot with Windows 10 secure boot enabled, as the restart does not show the grub menu. I tried it in live mode. To solve the wireless driver problem I followed as described to this page:
http://p-s.co.nz/wordpress/dual-boot-ubuntu-16-04-on-win-10-acer-aspire-e15/

open a terminal

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
```

If it reports that the file already exists, that’s fine, just continue.

With a temporary working internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo cp board.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo cp firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Your wireless should be working; if not, try a reboot.