# Ubuntu 22.04 wifi icon showing only sometimes and connecting

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 22.04

I have a HP Pavilion Windows 11 laptop. I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 on dual boot. However,the wifi icon is showing sometimes only.

I tried to check for additional drivers but none found.
I tried the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

I am completely new to this. Could anyone please help me step by step to fix this issue?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/258616/how-can-i-debug-my-wireless-problem