ASUS TUF Gaming - No internet connections
I just installed Kubuntu in an ASUS TUF gaming laptop, but I can't access the internet.
I tested: Ubuntu, kubuntu, Debian, Windows and others, but I have the same problem.
I tested other ASUS laptops, but I have the same problem.

You need to add more details. e.g. Are you trying wifi or ethernet? What hardware? Any useful log output in sudo dmesg? can you ping 8.8.8.8

@moo i use wifi, hardware: ram 16 GB Memory: 512 GB for more details just tag me

No one will be able to solve your generic internet access problem without more info. Read https://askubuntu.com/questions/258616/how-can-i-debug-my-wireless-problem Edit your original question with details
